# JAVA : regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

Can't find why my function that detect if in the targeted text there is a match for a certain regular expression does not work for this example:

regular expression:

```
"(?s).*<name>.+</name>.*​"
```

targeted text:

```
<queryContextResponse>
  <contextResponseList>
    <contextElementResponse>
      <contextElement>
        <entityId type="Room" isPattern="false">
          <id>Room1</id>
        </entityId>
        <contextAttributeList>
          <contextAttribute>
            <name>pressure</name>
            <type>integer</type>
            <contextValue>720</contextValue>
          </contextAttribute>
          <contextAttribute>
            <name>temperature</name>
            <type>float</type>
            <contextValue>23</contextValue>
          </contextAttribute>
        </contextAttributeList>
      </contextElement>
      <statusCode>
        <code>200</code>
        <reasonPhrase>OK</reasonPhrase>
      </statusCode>
    </contextElementResponse>
  </contextResponseList>
</queryContextResponse>
```

the function

```
    private boolean isStringContainsReg(String reg, String text){
        try
        {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(reg);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
            if (matcher.find()) {   
                return true;
            } 
        }
        catch(PatternSyntaxException e){            
            e.printStackTrace();            
        }
        return false;
    }
```

However when I test it on this online website, it works:
http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/

Comment: If you're going to parse XML, use an XML parser and not regexes.

Comment: well, on my computer it returns true (i simply assigned your xml to string)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/706695

Comment: @pezetem it returns false for me 1) in java code 2)  on java regex tester 3) on regexr

Answer (score 0):

changing the pattern to `(?s).*?<name>.+</name>.*​?` solves the issues - I just replaced `.*` wildcards to the non-greedy `.*?`. And by the way, there is the method [`String#matches(String regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) which does pretty much what your function `isStringContainsReg` does...